# Check if list exist sharepoint online using REST api

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-server, office-365

I am creating a functionality where I need to check if a particular list exist in SharePoint online site/web. The catch here is there would be more than 10000 lists where I am checking.
I found a way to check using CSOM code which takes a minute to come back with the result.
I am looking for a way which would respond to me faster. I guess REST would have unique URL for the list hence tried that but not able to find any proper information on this. I am looking for suggestions.
Any suggestion will be of great help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know what List to look for? Or are you *searching* for a list?

Comment: We have the list title with us...

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the REST API as below

```
https://siteurl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Test100')
```

If the list doesn't exists then you can expect below response

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>-1, System.ArgumentException</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">List 'Test100' does not exist at site with URL 'https://siteurl'.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

Comment: How fast would that be any idea??

Comment: It will be under a second.

Comment: But what if the list is in a subsite?

Comment: You can format the URL accordingly like `http://sitecollection/site/site/_api..`

Comment: The error that u have listed above does it come in success or on error of ajax call??

Comment: If the list exists the status code of the response is 200 - OK (runs the success function), 
if not the status code of response is 404 (not found), ajax call runs the 'error' function