# Check whether List/Libray exists using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest

I have a requirement where I need to verify whether the list/library with given name already exists or not.

I am implementing REST API Calls from C# so [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184115/check-if-list-exist-sharepoint-online-using-rest-api) post does not help me as I am not getting error message given in this post in C# `catch`. I am always getting

```
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

error, and I can use this error message to identify whether list/library exists or not

Another approach is also there to get all the list available and then iterate it and find your list name within that but this approach I can't implement as I am having large number of list/library so this approach will bring my code performance down.

So I am in search of an Ultimate REST endpoint URL using which I can directly get whether the list/library exists or not.

I referred [Complete basic operations using SharePoint 2013 REST endpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx)  and [Lists and list items REST API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx) but I was unable to find such direct endpoint url.

So if you have gone through this requirement then please suggest an proper approach or guideline.

I can't use CSOM or SSOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter lists by title using odata and count results.
url pattern:

```
http://{your_site}/_api/Web/Lists?$filter=title eq '{your_list_title}'
```

Comment: Feeling laughing to myself. how can I miss this simple approach. Thanks man, now I am able to identify my requirement.

Comment: Will this work for SharePoint 2010 also?

Comment: In SP2010 you have odata 2.0 endpoint:
`http://{your_site}/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/{your_list_name}`
So you have to check response status

Answer (score 1):

You can also use PnP JavaScript library, which is open source and developed  using SharePoint REST API.

To  check the list, use the below snippet,

```
$pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('Site Awssets').get().then(function(result) {
console.log('List Exists');
}).catch(function(err) {
console.log('List not found');
});
```

To know more about PnP, check the below links,

https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-JS-Core

http://www.ktskumar.com/2016/06/introduction-pnp-js-core-library/
https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Install-and-Use